# R data.tree enumerate the hierarchy

Tags: r, tree, hierarchy, enumerate

I'm a newbie with data.tree and like to enumerate a huge hierarchy with a couple of dimensions. 
Actually I'm struggeling and iterating with a nested loop and using climb is very awful.

```
library(data.tree)    
for(i2 in 1:2) {
  for(i3 in 1:2) {
  h2 <- acme$Climb(position = c(1,i2))$path
  h3 <- acme$Climb(position = c(1,i2,i3))$path
  print(sprintf("%d.%d.%d",1,i2, i3))
  print(sprintf("%d.%d",1,i2))
 }
 }
```

1  Acme Inc.                       1
2   ¦--Accounting                   1.1
3   ¦   ¦--New Software             1.1.1
4   ¦   °--New Accounting Standards 1.1.2
5   ¦--Research                    1.2
6   ¦   ¦--New Product Line        1.2.1
7   ¦   °--New Labs                1.2.2
8   °--IT                         1.3
9       ¦--Outsource              1.3.1
10      ¦--Go agile               1.3.2
11      °--Switch to R            1.3.3

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Maybe Get is all you need. Make sure you read the vignettes.

Comment: In the original acme I haven't  the enumeration such as 1 , 1.1, 1.1.1  etc.. and I'm looking for a more approriate way instead with the loop if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm still not sure what you want. Let's try this:

```
library(data.tree)
data(acme)

NodeName <- function(node) {
  if (node$isRoot) "1"
  else paste(NodeName(node$parent), node$position, sep = ".")
}

print(acme, nme = NodeName)
```

This yields:

```
                          levelName   nme
1  Acme Inc.                            1
2   ¦--Accounting                     1.1
3   ¦   ¦--New Software             1.1.1
4   ¦   °--New Accounting Standards 1.1.2
5   ¦--Research                       1.2
6   ¦   ¦--New Product Line         1.2.1
7   ¦   °--New Labs                 1.2.2
8   °--IT                             1.3
9       ¦--Outsource                1.3.1
10      ¦--Go agile                 1.3.2
11      °--Switch to R              1.3.3
```